# Odoo 15 notification navigate back to task/record

Tags: python, notifications, odoo, odoo-15

I am trying to send notification to user A then user B Approves a task. (but using the odoobot user)

```
notification_ids = [(0,0,{'res_partner_id':user_id.partner_id.id,'notification_type':'inbox'})]

self.sudo().message_post(subject=summary,body=summary_link,message_type='notification, subtype_xmlid='mail.mt_comment', author_id=odoo_bot_id.partner_id.id, notification_ids=notification_ids)
```

it was working but now i am going this:

ValueError: Posting a message should be done on a business document. Use message_notify to send a notification to an user.

```
if self._name == 'mail.thread' or not self.id or message_type == 'user_notification':
            raise ValueError(_('Posting a message should be done on a business document. Use message_notify to send a notification to an user.'))
```

what does `not self.id` mean

according to this I should use

```
message_notify_ids = [user_id.partner_id.id]

record.sudo().message_notify(partner_ids=message_notify_ids, parent_id=odoo_bot_id.partner_id.id, author_id=odoo_bot_id.partner_id.id,  body=summary_link, subject=summary)
```

this shows the popup notification but does not show in the index so the user can navigate to the task

[Odoo Form](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/odoo-15-notification-navigate-back-to-task-record-202813)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I logged `self.id` I got `NewId_26404` which is a temp id since the function was run in a compute.

Fix

```
record = record if isinstance(record.id,int) else record._origin
```

Note: discarding the changes did send the notification in my case, so it maybe better to add it in write function

I am open to suggestions if there is a better solution thank.